# Why is Xamarin Studio saying "version control operation failed due to unmerged path error" when I try to update my solution?

Tags: ios, version-control, github, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio to develop an iOS app on an iMac. The solution is hosted on Github. I have tried to update my solution with the server (github) version and have encountered some errors.

To pull back the latest version I went to: **Version Control > Update Solution**

I get the message **Version control operation failed: . Unmerged path: path_of_file_is_here**
[image]

It does this on about 4 of the files. On the Version Control panel it shows that this error is occurring at the **Stashing changes** point of the update.

I have spoken to the Dev and I can see that those files have been moved in the folder structure. They have been moved into a new sub folder on his/pushed version. Could  this have caused the update issue?

I have tried removing the 4 files from my project and re updating but I get the same errors. **Do I have to delete them from my hard disk too?**

Is it caused because I have made edits to my local version of those files?

**In the future how can errors like this be avoided?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the github desktop tool itself and selecting ok. It will tell you more and allow you to fix the changes. My guess is that you have conflicts in your code with the changes already stored on github.

Are you the only one working on this project? If not it most likely means someone else has changed those pieces and pushed them.

Again use the github application, it is free, to see what is going on.  I do not use the built in github interface. I had initial issue with it and just went back to my favorite. Using the external tool also makes it easier to manage if using other dev environments.

Comment: the github desktop tool is so much better than xamarin's version control options

Comment: Fully agree, I have experimented with the xamarin one after your post and said no way!